# How to install the latest patch version of a package with chocolatey?

Tags: windows, installation, chocolatey

I need Python 3.8 on my box and decided to install it with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).

I see there are a lot of them:

```
> choco list python3 -e --all

Chocolatey v0.12.1
python3 3.10.2 [Approved]
python3 3.10.1 [Approved]
python3 3.10.0 [Approved]
python3 3.9.10 [Approved]
[...]
python 3.9.0 [Approved]
python 3.8.10 [Approved]
python 3.8.9 [Approved]
python 3.8.8 [Approved]
[...]
```

For the sake of testing I went with 3.8.9, to see whether I could upgrade after that:

```
> choco install python -e --version 3.8.9
```

The installation went smooth and completed as expected.
Now I want the latest 3.8 which is 3.8.10, but:

```
> choco upgrade python --noop
```

says it would install 3.10.2:

```
Chocolatey v0.12.1
_ Chocolatey:ChocolateyUpgradeCommand - Noop Mode _

You have python v3.8.9 installed. Version 3.10.2 is available based on your source(s).

Chocolatey can upgrade 1/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Did you know the proceeds of Pro (and some proceeds from other
 licensed editions) go into bettering the community infrastructure?
 Your support ensures an active community, keeps Chocolatey tip-top,
 plus it nets you some awesome features!
 https://chocolatey.org/compare
```

and I couldn't manage to find how to express "the latest 3.8":

```
> choco upgrade python --noop --version 3.8

Chocolatey v0.12.1
_ Chocolatey:ChocolateyUpgradeCommand - Noop Mode _
A newer version of python (v3.8.9) is already installed.
 Use --allow-downgrade or --force to attempt to upgrade to older versions, or use side by side to allow multiple versions.

Chocolatey can upgrade 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - python - A newer version of python (v3.8.9) is already installed.
 Use --allow-downgrade or --force to attempt to upgrade to older versions, or use side by side to allow multiple versions.
```

or

```
> choco upgrade python --noop --version 3.8.x

Chocolatey v0.12.1
_ Chocolatey:ChocolateyUpgradeCommand - Noop Mode _
'3.8.x' is not a valid version string.
Nome parametro: version
```

Comment: If you use `--allow-downgrade` or `--force` with 3.8.9 what version exactly is installed?  I would imagine you are trying to perform a corner case operation, which means, you will need to specifically indicate you want to install `3.8.10` which means you have to know it exists.

Comment: @Ramhound `--force` is not recommended by per the docs, and I'm looking for a supported solution; `--allow-downgrade` seems to allow installing a previous version, which is otherwise blocked, but I'm looking for the next. Since Python 3.x may not be totally compatible with 3.(x+1) (you may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63247803/3127111) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63248183/3127111)), I wanted to see whether choco is able to upgrade fixing some version scheme.

Comment: It’s only a test, you can easily restore the configuration, after you get the results. I am not going to look at anything until you provide those results

Comment: @Ramhound Just did it today, as I needed 3.7 after having worked with 3.10 on another script; `--allow-downgrade` allowed installing the previous version, otherwise I had been stopped with an error that a newer version is already installed. After your comment, however, I had to install Java: I guess this is a matter of how Python has been packaged in choco, because if you run `choco find temurin -a` you'll see different packages for the different Java majors (8, 11, 16, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar conundrum after I used choco to install 3.9.0. Shortly after doing it I realised there is actually 3.9.12 available and I couldn't workout how to update/upgrade with choco without jumping to 3.10.4 as it threatened to do after running:

```bsh
choco upgrade python --what-if
```

so I did this instead:

```bsh
choco install python --version=3.9.12
```

and it looks fine so far...